# How does Java handles object of generic class when deserializing?

Tags: java, generics, serialization, deserialization

Here is a very simple generic class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class GenericDemoObject<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    T date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return date.getClass().getName() + ':' + date.toString();
    }
}
```

I then created an instance of `GenericDemoObject` with T typed to `org.joda.time.LocalDate`, and serialized it to disk. Then I tried to deserialize it with the following code:

```
private static Object deserialize(String fileName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
        return in.readObject();
    }
}

// LocalDate is java.time.LocalDate
GenericDemoObject<LocalDate> obj = (GenericDemoObject<LocalDate>) deserialize("GenericDemoObject.ser");
```

I can't understand how the deserialization works. Why does it not throw a ClassCastException?

Edited:

More precisely, I mean `obj` is a reference of type GenericDemoObject, however the deserilized object's date field is of type org.joda.time.LocalDate. How can that assignment work?

Comment: Why do you think there will be a ClassCastException, you're returning an Object everything is an object!

Comment: @alibttb yes, `deserialize` returns an object. More precisely I didn't get the point how the reference `obj` can point to an object whose date deserialized is joda LocalDate. Am I missing something?

Comment: Instance of `LocalDate` is insante of `Object` so no problem there. Casting it to `Object` will work fine.

Comment: *however the deserilized object's date field is of type org.joda.time.LocalDate. How can that assignment work?* Why do you think it should not work?

Comment: @Antoniossss Shouldn't obj points to an object of GenericDemoObject with type java LocalDate? here the deserialized one is in joda time.

Comment: You better check actual LocalDate packages in both cases. You probably got wrong imports thats all. Still, object deserialized will be the same as it was during serialization - no matter to whatever you cast it afterwards.

Comment: @Antoniossss I am quite sure the imports are good in both cases.

Comment: You can be quite sure, super sure, absolutely sure, and I am telling you you are wrong. Even if you use default serialization mechanism **the actual implementation class name is stored in serialized content**. Due to erasure, every generic type is OBJECT. The fact that you are declaring it as some type does not makes it of that type - especially if we are talking about generics. If you declare it as ANY generic type, it still will work as there is **NO CASTING**. Generic type is only a **compile time type**. Since you are doing in fact **unsafe typing**  you will get error when you move on.

Comment: aren't `org.joda.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.LocalDate` identical in fields? @Antoniossss

Comment: well they are not, could @qingl97 post more code or give us a repository to check the code?

Comment: @alibttb thats not JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: yes true, thanks for the information, your comments taught me new things about serialization, and I see they aren't identical, more on as you mentioned: **the actual implementation class name is stored in serialized content**. @Antoniossss

Answer (score 0):

After testing the case you posted in your question I confirm that you won't get an exception by merely casting a generic as you did, the real casting never happens until you access the field `date`, check the following code:
public class Main {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.joda.time.LocalDate date = org.joda.time.LocalDate.now();
        GenericDemoObject<org.joda.time.LocalDate> gdo = new GenericDemoObject<>();
        gdo.date = date;
        try {
            serialize("GenericDemoObject.ser", gdo);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            GenericDemoObject<java.time.LocalDate> obj1 = (GenericDemoObject<java.time.LocalDate>) deserialize("GenericDemoObject.ser");//no exception
            GenericDemoObject<String> obj2 = (GenericDemoObject<String>) deserialize("GenericDemoObject.ser");//no exception
            LocalDate date1 = obj1.date;//The exception is thrown here
            String date2 = obj2.date;//The exception is thrown here

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Object deserialize(String fileName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
            return in.readObject();
        }
    }

    private static void serialize(String fileName, Object object) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
            out.writeObject(object);
        }
    }
}

class GenericDemoObject<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    T date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return date.getClass().getName() + ':' + date.toString();
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

**Note:**
Reading through comments again I think [Antoniossss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527544/antoniossss) really answered but didn't really post it as an answer.